# Entanglement between Tkinter Checkbuttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

Hey so i'm making a program that has a checkbutton on the main window and a toplevel window that has one aswell. the problem is that for some reason the toplevel checkbutton affects the state of the main checkbutton, or the main checkbutton mimics the top level one (if you check/uncheck the toplevel one, the main one checks/unchecks aswell). Here's an example code which displays the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

def toplevel():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.geometry('200x50')

    top_chekbutton = tk.Checkbutton(top, text='top')

    top_chekbutton.pack()

    top.mainloop()

main = tk.Tk()
main.geometry('200x50')

open_top = tk.Button(main, text='open top', command=toplevel)

main_checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(main, text='main')

main_checkbutton.pack()
open_top.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

i didn't define the state variables because they don't seem to be the source of the problem. i'm using python 3.7.7 and tkinter 8.6 on win10. 
plz help :(

Comment: Just bind a `variable` to those `checkbutton` widgets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-are-these-python-tkinter-checkbuttons-linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864662)

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, every instance of `Checkbutton` should have a variable associated with it. If you don't, a default value will be used that is identical for all `Checkbuttons`. All widgets that share the same variable will display the same value.

You can verify this yourself by printing out the value of `top_chekbutton.cget("variable")` and `main_checkbutton.cget("variable")`. In both cases the value is "!checkbutton" (at least, with the version of python I'm using).

So, assign a variable for your checkbuttons, such as a `BooleanVar`, `IntVar`, or `StringVar`.

```
main_var = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
main_checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(main, text='main')
```

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense but on my actual program they have different variables and they still do the same thing :C

Comment: @savyexe: I can only respond to code that you’ve posted. If the checkboxes are “entangled”, the only explanation is that they have the same variable. If your variables are local, this can be a side effect of that.

Comment: welp, that worked just fine except because the actual value of the variable didn't change, so i added a command function to the checkbutton to change the value of the variable whenever the it's pressed and now it works, thanks for the advice :D

Comment: @savyexe: you shouldn't need to do that. The checkbutton will automatically set the value of the associated variable. If it's not doing that, you're doing something wrong.